# UIAutomation is it possible to get elements name using x and y cordinates

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, unit-testing, automation

Currently i am  trying to create a 'soak test' for my iPhone app. i am randomly tapping at set x and y co ordinates. Is it possible to find the element that i am tapping?

any ideas would be great

Dan

Comment: i am currently developing this using automation, which is written in java script

Answer (score 1):

I head somebody talk about "monkey" which apparently does these kind of things for Android, maybe google related "monkey alternatives" or "Monkey Ios"

Answer (score 0):

Storing your elements in a dictionary and use the coordinates as a key would be a possibility.

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%f", tap.Xcoordinate, tap.YCoordinate];
[dictionary objectForKey: key];
```

Comment: thanks for your ideas, but automation is written in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way iterate through all the subviews in the view and check the intersection point using CGRectInsect function. It returns a bool and then you can get that object.

Comment: thanks for your ideas, but automation is written in javascript